# Using LaTeX to create quiz questions and then export to QTI format

Tags: exam, export

My university uses Canvas LMS which includes the ability to admin quizzes online.  One drawback is the interface for writing quizzes is web based and rather primitive.  For example one can't imbed any comments, add descriptors to help organize things, etc.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to export LaTeX to QTI or similar format.  I have come across an R package that seems to do it called exams, but it seems rather involved and I'd love to just stick with LaTeX (or md).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at text2qti at https://github.com/gpoore/text2qti. It converts markdown quizzes to qti.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  It looks like it does what I need.  I will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Looks great.  I'm going to use it this semester extensively.  I only wish you could set the question's ID somehow so you can update previously uploaded questions.